# change the color of specific item in recylerview android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

hello i want to change the color of specific items in recycler view. 
i have done this using this code.

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
clickME click;
View view;

ArrayList<String > data;

public CustomAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> data) {
    this.context=context;
    this.data=data;
    inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);

}

 @Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row,parent,false);

    MyViewHolder holder=new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


    int select=4;
    if(select == position) {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        Toast.makeText(context,""+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#214F4B"));
         Toast.makeText(context,""+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    holder.tv_title.setText(data.get(position));



}
```

but the output is
[image]

[image]

i have successfully change the background color of item in position 4, but when i scroll down the background color of item at position 14 also change. i don't know why this happening kindly solve my issue

Comment: What is `view` in `onBindViewHolder()`? Code isn't complete

Comment: @SergeyGlotov check the code and solve it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is you're not recycling your `view` View. You have not posted your ViewHolder code, but you should use `holder.view.setBackgroundColor(...)` instead of `view.setBackgroundColor(...)` in your `onBindViewHolder` method.

Comment: can you please tell me how to change the color of first five items color?

Comment: You can do the same you're doing now, but asking for `position <= 4`

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't reuse view from `onCreateViewHolder()`. Code will be something like this:

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);

    MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    int select = 4;
    if (select == position) {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#214F4B"));
        Toast.makeText(context, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    holder.tv_title.setText(data.get(position));
}
```

Comment: How do I set the background color of a particular item position at runtime.

Comment: @DPrince Exactly like he did it above.